# Getting local storage to save when browser is reloaded in javaScript

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am trying to get items from local storage on my to do list. They are saved in local storage but I 'm struggling to figure out how to keep them on the page when I refresh the browser. I am new to JavaScript and trying to use it as much possible hence the changing of css styling. I know it's better practice to do this through css but as I said I'm forcing myself to work in JavaScript as much as possible.

```
// task list section
const taskBtn = document.querySelector('.btn-blue');
let addTask = document.querySelector('.main-content');
let taskPanel;
let taskPara;
let deletebtn;
let values;

//Event Listeners
taskBtn.addEventListener('click', addPanel);

function addPanel (event){
    //Create div section
    createDiv();

    // Create paragraph
    createPara();

    //create buttons
    checkList();

    createBtn();

    removeContent();

};

//functions
//Create Div
function createDiv (event) {
    taskPanel = document.createElement('ul');
    taskPanel.setAttribute('class', 'task-added');
     //set css styles
    taskPanel.style.cssText = "display: flex; background-color: white; border: 2px solid #000; border-radius: 5px; margin-top: 2rem; align-items: center; justify-content: space-between;"
    addTask.appendChild(taskPanel);
}

//Create Paragraph
function createPara (event) {
      taskPara = document.createElement('li');
      taskPara.classList.add('para-1');
      const addInput = document.querySelector('input');
      taskPara.innerText = addInput.value;
      taskPara.style.cssText = "display: flex; width: 80%; height: 50%; margin-left: 2rem; align-items: center;"
      taskPanel.appendChild(taskPara);
      getItems(addInput.value);
      addInput.value = '';
}

function checkList (event) {
    const check = document.createElement('div');
    check.classList.add('check-box');
    check.innerHTML = '<form><input type="radio"></form>';
    taskPanel.appendChild(check);
    check.addEventListener('click', () => {
        taskPara.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
    })
}

//Create Button
function createBtn (event) {
    deletebtn = document.createElement('button');
    deletebtn.setAttribute('class', 'btn-icon');
    deletebtn.innerHTML = '<i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i>';
    //set css styles
    deletebtn.style.cssText = "background-color: yellow; color: red; font-size: 1.5em; border: none; outline: none; padding: 1rem; cursor: pointer;";
    taskPanel.appendChild(deletebtn);
}

function removeContent () {
    deletebtn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        event.target.closest('.task-added').remove();
    });
}

function getItems (value) {
    let values;

    if(localStorage.getItem(values) === null) {
        values = [];
    } else {
        values.JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(values));
    }
    values.push(value);
    localStorage.setItem('values', JSON.stringify(values));
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If you got a functional code then you need to add event listener on load and repopulate all of your field from the data you have in local storage.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting data into `localStorage` using "values" as a key `localStorage.setItem('values', JSON.stringify(values));`. You need to get it using `"values"` as a string meaning `const values = localStorage.getItem("values:);`

Also you might want to move `localStorage.setItem('values', JSON.stringify(values));`
somewhere else.